# Master e Detail em delphi, com SchemaAdapter, só grava da segunda vez em diante

Tags: delphi, firebird, firedac

Estou usando Delphi 10.1, Firebird 2.5 com Firedac. Possuo 3 FDQuery, todas com CachedUpdates = true, sendo 1 MASTER, e 2 detail. No bd, as FK apontam para o ID da tabela master. No aplicativo, mastersource, MasterField e IndexFieldName preenchidos conforme [este link](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Caching_Updates_(FireDAC)).

Uso um TFDSchemaAdapter, todas as 3 Querys possuem o campo SchemaAdapter apontando para o FDSchemaAdapter1. Até ai ok, funciona, pega a chave na hora de gravar e armazena nas duas query detail. Porém, usando o código abaixo para salvar permanente no bd, da primeira tentativa ele dispara erro (1 erro para cada linha nas detalhes), e pior: persiste a gravação na tabela MASTER, e não grava nada em nenhuma das 2 detail.

Então, fecho o form, permanecendo com o aplicativo aberto, abro o form novamente, posto novos dados em todas as 3 query, e ao disparar o código abaixo, funciona como esperado, disparando 0 erro, e funciona ok todas as demais vezes.

Nenhum erro é disparado quando dou append, insert, post.

Onde estou errando?

```
//Código do botão para salvar 
dm.FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
iErrors := FDSchemaAdapter1.ApplyUpdates;
if iErrors = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('não deu erros: '+IntToStr(iErrors));
    FDSchemaAdapter1.CommitUpdates;
    dm.FDConnection1.Commit;
  end else
    begin
      MsgBxErroWarn('Deu erro: '+IntToStr(iErrors));
      dm.FDConnection1.Rollback;
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi. Mais de um erro estava causando isto. O primeiro, um Form que estava carregando com o aplicativo deixava uma Transação aberta (estava em Autocreate, e não em avaliable forms do Delphi), apesar de nada neste form disparar um StartTransaction a não ser que fosse clicado, checando com o comando InTransaction notei uma transação em aberto. Movendo este form para "avaliable forms" resolveu.

Corrigindo esta, ainda havia outro problema quando chamo, no sql da Master "A.ID as APELIDO" e colocar o campo APELIDO no MASTERFIELD das querys detail, aparentemente funciona, mas dá erro ao enviar o comando FDSchemaAdapter1.ApplyUpdates. Se eu deixar na sql da master simplesmente A.ID, e usar o campo ID para atribuir ao MASTERFIELD das querys detail, funciona.

```
if (dm.FDConnection1.InTransaction = False) then
begin
  dm.FDConnection1.StartTransaction;
end;
iErrors := FDSchemaAdapter1.ApplyUpdates(0);
if iErrors = 0 then
  begin
    ShowMessage('não deu erros: '+IntToStr(iErrors));
    fdqVendaCaixa.CommitUpdates;
    fdqVendaCaixaItens.CommitUpdates;
    fdqVendaPgtoC.CommitUpdates;
    dm.FDConnection1.Commit;
  end else
    begin
      MsgBxErroWarn('Deu erro: '+IntToStr(iErrors));
      dm.FDConnection1.Rollback;
    end;
```